# How to clone multi Azure VM

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, azure-virtual-machine

I have original Azure VM.
And , I want to clone multi Azure VM from original Azure VM.
(For example, 100 VMs)
I created a managed disk and attempted to clone it.
And one clone was made, but no more.
I could only create one clone from one original VM.
How can I create 100 clone VMs from one original VM?
I would like to copy the files etc. contained in the original VM to the clone as well.

Comment: Try ARM Templates:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/copy-resources

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Azure Backup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-vms-introduction) and [Restore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/about-azure-vm-restore):

[How to restore Azure VM data in Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-arm-restore-vms)

> Quickly creates and gets a basic VM up and running from a restore point.
> You can specify a name for the VM, select the resource group and virtual network (VNet) in which it will be placed, and specify a storage account for the restored VM. The new VM must be created in the same region as the source VM.

Comment: thank you for answer.
I try it.
But I use a spot VM, not a regular VM.
So even if you back up a spot VM, it will be restored as a normal VM.
Is there any way to backup the spot VM and restore the spot VM?